# How to use the variables from Table in calculation

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation, variable

New to the site and *Mathematica*. I'm trying to use the finite element method to get a temperature profile. So if $q_0=f(T_0,T_1)$, $q_n=f(T_{n-1},T_n)$ and we also know that $T_1-T_0=T_2-T_1=T_3-T_2=\dotso=T_n-T_{n-1}$ We can solve for the $T_i$s. I know there is a way one can create the desired amount of variables by using `Table[Subscript[T, n], {n, 0, 999}]`, but how to use them in the equations? I guess what I'm saying is how to solve a large amount of equations. Let me know if my question is not clear enough, I'll try to explain everything I know.

```
temp[Conc_, Kcond_, x_, h_] := 
 NSolve[Qrad[Conc] == sigma*T0^4 + Qcond[Kcond, x, T0, T1] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T19, T20] == sigma*T20^4 + Qconv[h, T20] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T0, T1] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T1, T2] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T1, T2] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T2, T3] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T2, T3] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T3, T4] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T3, T4] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T4, T5] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T4, T5] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T5, T6] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T5, T6] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T6, T7] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T6, T7] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T7, T8] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T7, T8] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T8, T9] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T8, T9] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T9, T10] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T9, T10] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T10, T11] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T10, T11] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T11, T12] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T11, T12] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T13, T14] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T13, T14] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T14, T15] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T14, T15] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T15, T16] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T15, T16] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T16, T17] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T16, T17] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T17, T18] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T17, T18] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T18, T19] && 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T18, T19] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T19, T20] && T0 > 0 &&
    T1 > 0 && T2 > 0 && T3 > 0 && T4 > 0 && T5 > 0 && T6 > 0 && 
   T7 > 0 && T8 > 0 && T9 > 0 && T10 > 0 && T11 > 0 && T12 > 0 && 
   T13 > 0 && T14 > 0 && T15 > 0 && T16 > 0 && T17 > 0 && T18 > 0 && 
   T19 > 0 && T20 > 0, {T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, 
   T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20}]
temp[3, 12, 0.01, 250]
```

Basically this is what I want but instead of typing them all out(which I can't) I was wondering if there is a way to simplify this. Thanks!

Comment: It might help if you specify the equations you want to use. As opposed to asking how to use variables in equations. Additionally, the documentation for `Solve` and `Reduce` describe how to solve system of equations in *Mathematica*.

Comment: thanks. I think my problem is not how to solve them but how to define the variables in a simpler way. I just can't find any examples for that and since I don't have any programming experience this got me a lot of trouble.

Comment: Your equations seem identical except at the first and last time steps, so why not use `Table` again to generate the equations? The inequalities for example can be generated by `Table[ic>0,{ic,list}]` when `list=Table[Subscript[T, n], {n, 0, 999}]`.

Comment: ...Although I don't recommend using `Subscript`s. I would use `T[n]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
temp[Conc_, Kcond_, x_, h_] := NSolve[
  And @@ Join[
    {Qrad[Conc] == sigmaT0^4 + Qcond[Kcond, x, T[0], T[1]], Qcond[Kcond, x, T[19], T[20]] == sigmaT20^4 + Qconv[h, T[20]]}
    , Array[Qcond[Kcond, x, T[#], T[# + 1]] == Qcond[Kcond, x, T[# + 1], T[# + 2]] &, 19, 0]
    , T[#] > 0 & /@ Range[0, 20]
  ]
  , Table[T[k], {k, 0, 20}]
 ]
```

There are a couple of different ways to create lists automated lists of the type you're looking for. Embedded in the code above are some examples. The most straightforward is the last:

```
Table[T[k], {k, 0, 20}]
(* {T[0], T[1], T[2], T[3], T[4], T[5], T[6], T[7], T[8], T[9], T[10], T[11], T[12], T[13], T[14], T[15], T[16], T[17], T[18], T[19], T[20]} *)
```

Two others involve `Array` (look it up in the documentation) and `Map` (`/@`) (look it up in the documentation. In addition, I am using pure functions. For instance, `T[#] > 0 &`. This is shorthand for

```
Function[{x}, T[x] > 0]
```

and it is an object that when you attach `[a]` to it, it puts `a` in the spot of `#` (`x`):

```
T[#] > 0 & [a]
Function[{x}, T[x] > 0][a]
(* T[a] > 0 *)
(* T[a] > 0 *)
```

Take this example and run with it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. There are a lot of command that I've never seen before so I guess it will take a bit time to understand. But this definitely seems enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

As `march` pointed out in the comment it would be better to use `Array`.
Then you can define a function like

```
   f[i_] := Qcond[Kcond, x, T[i], T[i + 1]] == 
   Qcond[Kcond, x, T[i + 1], T[i + 2]]
```

Use `Thread` to write the conditional part 1

```
  c1[n_] := And @@ Thread[Array[f, n, 0]]
```

For the remaining part again use `Thread`

```
  c2[n_] := And @@ Thread[Array[T, n, 0] > 0]
```

Finaly your variable list

```
   var = Table[T[i], {i, 1, 20}]
```

Then your main function simplies to

```
 temp[Conc_, Kcond_, x_, h_] := 
  NSolve[Qrad[Conc] == sigma*T0^4 + Qcond[Kcond, x, T0, T1] && 
  Qcond[Kcond, x, T19, T20] == sigma*T20^4 + Qconv[h, T20] && 
   c1[19] && c2[19], var]
```

Comment: Again thanks for the help. I probably need to familiarize myself with all these new terms but the idea presented here is really helpful.